# Is it possible to use one line contracts in Liquid Haskell?

Tags: haskell, liquid-haskell

Liquid Haskell uses comments like `{-@ ... @-}` for contracts block. Is it possible (with command line option, config file) to specify to use one line comments style like `-- ...` for contracts ?

Comment: Those are not comments, but "contracts" that you put in between the `{-@ ... @-}`. Yes you can use `--` for *comments*.

Comment: OK, correct terminology is "contract". I tried to use `--` for contracts, but LH ignores them, so, is it possible to use it for _contracts_?

Comment: as far as I know, it is not, `--` will ignore what is put in the rest of that line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Looking at the source code for Liquid Haskell (in the file `src/Language/Haskell/Liquid/GHC/Interface.hs`), extraction of specifications is performed by the function `extractSpecComment`.  This searches for comments of type `AnnBlockComment` (which are comments in the `{-...-}` style) for those with an initial `{-@` and terminating `@-}`.  No other comment style is supported.

Answer (score 1):

No the only way to comment is putting yout comment :

```
{% comment %} Like this. {% endcomment %}
```